# python3.6 can pickle instance method staticmethod classmethod, but document say None?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle, python-multiprocessing

in python3.6

```
class C:
    class_var = 'class_var'
    @staticmethod
    def s():
        pass
    @classmethod
    def c(cls):
        pass
    def i(self):
        pass


 import pickle
 pickle.dumps(C.class_var) # ok
 pickle.dumps(C.i) #ok
 pickle.dumps(C.s) # ok
 pickle.dumps(C.c) # ok
```

but in python3.4
above code is error!
and the least document say nothing about it.
neither saying two version pickling moudle change, nor saying pickleiing is ok now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[this patch](https://bugs.python.org/issue23611) landed in python3.5 and seems to be what you're looking for.

[Here's](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/58e4134a1cf668a16006b896fca093d5a79966e3) the associated commit.

[here's](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html#pickle) the entry in the changelog for python3.5

The patch briefly mentions "unbound methods" as a possible usecase though it is mostly centered around unpickling in deep namespaces / nested classes.